# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on an event handler

Tags: c#

I get the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on this line of code: 
`LaneControllerLane(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

This is the whole program:

**MainForm**

```
public static event EventHandler LaneControllerDevice;
public static event EventHandler LaneControllerLane;
internal void LaneMessage(string message)
    {

        CommonEntitiesForTollApps.LANE = message.Split('|')[0];
        CommonEntitiesForTollApps.DEVICE = message.Split('|')[1];

        pnlForControl.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            LaneControllerLane(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }));
    }
```

**ControlForm**

```
private void ctrlLane_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MainForm.LaneControllerDevice += new EventHandler(CheckSignal);
            MainForm.LaneControllerLane += new EventHandler(CheckLaneOperation);

        }

private void CheckLaneOperation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(CommonEntitiesForTollApps.LANE == this.LaneName)
        {
            switch (DEVICE)
            {
                case "Scanner":
                    lblScanner.Text = "1";
                    break;
                case "Printer":
                    lblPrinter.Text = "1";
                    break;
                case "RFID":
                    lblTransactionType.Text = CommonEntitiesForTollApps.TRANSACTION_TYPE;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Before raising an event you should check it anyone subscribed checking for nulls. check the duplicated link or Mighty's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
LaneControllerLane(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

with

```
LaneControllerLane?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

This is how you fire an event. The `?` is the short form of a null check: [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

If you are using older frameworks you have to use

```
if(LaneControllerLane != null)
{
    LaneControllerLane.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

instead.

Comment: Could be improved: Please note the `?` operator is framework specific. For older frameworks a regular `if` could be used.

Comment: @bradbury9 Thx for the hint, edited my answer